# Get the width of a text element within SVG using D3 version 4

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

There are some similar questions related to finding the width of a text element. One has an answer for D3 version 3. This question is more specific for D3 version 4.

There seems to be a way to find the width of a text element - using getBBox().

But when I see the prototype of the text element, I find no getBBox(). Infact, I don't find anything useful to find the width.

[image: prototype of text element]

I am using d3 with react-faux-dom.

Comment: Are you looking in the node or the selection? [.getBBox()](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) is used on nodes not d3 selections.

Comment: This is what I see on the node. Maybe, it is because I am using react-faux-dom !!!

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure how react-faux-dom changes things.

Comment: Looking over it again, [it may be contained within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Answer (score 1):

Created a short snippet showing what I commented on in action. Creates a text element inside an SVG, then selects the elements node and calls `getBoundingClientRect()`. I am only outputting `.width`, but [there is more information under there too including position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```js
d3.select("#test").append("text").attr("id", "innerText").attr("x", "10px").attr("y", "20px").text("This is text");

var textRect = d3.select("#innerText").node().getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(textRect.width);
```

```css
text{stroke:black;}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg id="test"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```